# Global variable in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables

I want the `$year` variable to be available in all functions of my `PagesController`. I tried this code but I didn't succeed.

```php
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $dt = Carbon::parse();
        $year = $dt->year;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('pages.index');
    }

    public function about()
    {
        return view('pages.about', compact('year'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.create', compact('year'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**1. Option: Use the AppServiceProvider**

In this case $year is available to ALL views!

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Carbon;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('year', Carbon::parse()->year);
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**2. Option: Use a [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers)**

In this case, the variable is only available to the views where you need it.

Don't forget to add the newly created provider to `config/app.php`!

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Carbon;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using Closure based composers...
        view()->composer('pages.*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('year', Carbon::parse()->year);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**3. Use Blades [@inject-method](http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#service-injection)**

Within the views that need the year you could inject a Carbon instance like this:

```
@inject('carbon', 'Carbon\Carbon')

{{ $carbon->parse()->year }}
```

Comment: hello im new to laravel. how can i use the first option. do i need to declare something in pagesController.php cause i got an error of "Undefined variable: year". P.S im using laravel 5

Comment: If you've added the code to your `AppServiceProvider` like described, there's nothing else you need to do. What is throwing this error?

Comment: i use this.. public function about()
    {

      return $year ;
    } and the error is Undefined variable: year. i copied and paste your code.

Comment: For this to work you can't just return the variable `$year` because it gets shared with a view. You need to return a view from your function: `return view('pages.about')` and then you can access `$year` from your blade template like this: `{{ $year }}`

Comment: i see so this is directly shared in all view not in controller. thanks.

Comment: Correct. As you were just passing the year into the views I hope I unterstood correctly that essentially it's not needed in your controller but in your views.

Comment: yap thats correct i need the year to be pass on all views. thanks for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91361/discussion-between-tim-and-nixxx27).

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
//give private declaration
private $year;
public function __construct()
{
    $dt = Carbon::parse();
    $this->year = $dt->year;
}

public function index()
{
    return view('pages.index');
}

public function about()
{
    $year = $this->year;
    return view('pages.about',compact('year') );
}

public function create()
{
     $year = $this->year;
    return view('pages.create',compact('year') );
}
```

Comment: I try this `private $year;` and in function `$year = $this->year;
    return view('pages.about',compact('year') );` but in view it returns `null`?

Comment: here is what I done `private $superSupplier;` and `public function __construct() {pointedSupplier = Supplier::where( 'id', Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->id() )->with( 'supplier_role' )->first();} $this->superSupplier   = $pointedSupplier->supplier_role->supper_supplier;` this returns null

Answer (score 5):

You can create a global singleton within App::before event

```
App::before(function($request) {
    App::singleton('customYear', function(){
        $dt = Carbon::parse();
        $customYear = $dt->year;
        return $customYear;
    });

    // If you use this line of code then it'll be available in any view
    View::share('customYear', app('customYear'));

    //To get the same data in any controller you may use:
    $customYear = app('customYear');
});
```