# Laravel Controller - Pass a variable from function to function

Tags: php, laravel

So I have two functions named 'search' and 'pdfview'.

Every time I use the `search` function, I want to pass a query where it selects certain data to the `pdfview` function.

Here's my `search` function:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->period == 'Daily') {
        $datefrom = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
        $dateto = Carbon::now()->endOfDay();
    }
    elseif ($request->period == 'Weekly') {
        $datefrom = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
        $dateto = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();
    }
    elseif ($request->period == 'Monthly') {
        $datefrom = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
        $dateto = Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();
    }
    elseif ($request->period == 'Yearly') {
        $datefrom = Carbon::now()->startOfYear();
        $dateto = Carbon::now()->endOfYear();   
    }
    else {
        $datefrom = Carbon::parse($request->datefrom);
        $dateto = Carbon::parse($request->dateto);
    }

    $solditems = DB::table('orders')
        // ->join('orders', 'receipts.receipt_id', '=', 'orders.receipt_id')
        ->whereDate('orders.created_at', '>=', $datefrom)
        ->whereDate('orders.created_at', '<=', $dateto)
        ->where('status','=', 'served')
        ->select('orders.*', DB::raw('SUM(subtotal) as subtotal'), DB::raw('SUM(qty) as qty'))
        ->groupBy('item_id')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'dsc')
        ->get();

    return view('salesreports.sellingitems.index', compact('solditems'));
}
```

And here's my `pdfview` function:

```
public function pdfview(Request $request)
{
    $solditems = DB::table('orders')
        ->where('status', 'served')
        ->select('orders.*', DB::raw('SUM(subtotal) as subtotal'), DB::raw('SUM(qty) as qty'))
        ->groupBy('item_id')
        ->orderBy('qty', 'dsc')
        ->get();

    view()->share('solditems', $solditems);

    if ($request->has('download')) {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('salesreports.sellingitems.pdf');
        return $pdf->download('sellingitems-' . Carbon::now() . '.pdf');
    }

    return view('salesreports.sellingitems.pdf');
}
```

As you can see, the `pdfview` function has a default query for the $solditems. But I wanted that variable to come from my `search` function.

**UPDATE:** I managed to solve the problem using `session`.

Here's how you store with session:

```
session()->put('period', 'Daily');
```

and this is how you retrieve with session:

```
$period = $request->session()->get('period', 'default');
```

Comment: do you mean, you want to make `$solditems` data in `pdfview` be same with `search` value?

Comment: @elegisandi Yes! Exactly like that. And it should update whenever the `search` function runs.

Comment: I think you have to define `$datefrom` and `$dateto` globally in controller, then these values will be changes in search function call and you can use them in pdfView function

Comment: you can store the `$solditems` data in `search` function to session, then just pull it on the `pdfview` function

Comment: @SagarGautam Alright, I'll try searching on how to make a variable globally available. Thanks!

Comment: @elegisandi are there any disadvantages using sessions?

Comment: @JanArielSanJose it's very easy. You need to define initial value and will be changed as the search is called.

Comment: @SagarGautam Thank you for the suggestion but, I can't seem to understand what "define initial value" means.

Comment: i don't think there is. it will minimize sql queries in your case. unless you have to modify the query made from `search` method in `pdfview`

Comment: I want to say that `$datefrom` and `$dateto` should not be null :D

Comment: @SagarGautam Ohh, haha. I tried initializing it inside the class with `public static $datefrom = ' '` and tested it with `return $datefrom;` inside a function, it's says that it can't find that variable

Comment: see this question you will get idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942379/global-variable-in-laravel-controller

Comment: @SagarGautam Ohhhh, this is great. I'll give it a try and update you guys! Thanks, haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getSolditems()
{
    if (!isset($this->solditems)) {
        $solditems = DB::table('orders')
            // ->join('orders', 'receipts.receipt_id', '=', 'orders.receipt_id')
            ->whereDate('orders.created_at','>=', $datefrom)
            ->whereDate('orders.created_at', '<=', $dateto)
            ->where('status','=', 'served')
            ->select('orders.*', DB::raw('SUM(subtotal) as subtotal'), DB::raw('SUM(qty) as qty'))
            ->groupBy('item_id')
            ->orderBy('created_at','dsc')
            ->get();
        $this->solditems = $solditems;
    } else {
        $solditems = $this->solditems;
    }

    return $solditems;
}

public function search(Request $request)
{
    ....
    $solditems = getSolditems();
    ....
}

public function pdfview(Request $request)
{
    ....
    $solditems = getSolditems();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `$request->merge()` method to pass `$solditems` data to `pdfview()` method from `search()`

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
   ....
   $request->merge(['solditems'=>$solditems]);
   $this->pdfview()
}


public function pdfview(Request $request)
{
   $solditems = $request->get('solditems');
   ....
}
```

Comment: It gives an error that it should have a Request Instance, and when I do add it. $solditems can't be found at `pdfview` function.

Comment: In search update `$this->pdfview()` to `$this->pdfview($request)` and then try